# encoding either an int or NSInteger for state restoration

Tags: ios, objective-c, state-restoration

I am implementing state restoration in my app. The windows are restored fine, so now I am trying to encode certain properties of a view controller related to an index used to preserve the state of the view of the view controller. I have:

```
@property (nonatomic) int index; //prefer to use an int
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *testint; //I tried with NSInteger as well and got the same error code
```

And I added the following to my view controller .m file (also tried with NSInteger, but I'm pasting the int code)

```
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.index forKey:@"self.index"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self.index = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"self.index"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

Whether I use an int or an NSInteger, I get this same error message as soon as I type these out (can't build)

For

```
[coder encodeObject:self.index forKey:@"self.index"];
```

the error message is "Incompatible integet to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type id."

And for

```
self.index = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"self.index"];
```

the error is "incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'id'"

Clearly these errors are one of the same. But there must be a way to encode an int, and even if there isn't, why do I get these errors even when I use NSInteger test int and replace all the above with self.testint instead of self.index. In the latter case, I am using a pointer.

So my question is how DO I encode either an int (preferable) or an NSInteger? Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider looking at [either](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001294-BBCBDHBI) of the relevant [pieces of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had not found the one about encoding c data types. Quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you really trying to use pointer for integer '*testint'. I think it is rather, 'testint'.
And the following could be able to fix your error.

```
@property (nonatomic) int index; //prefer to use an int
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger testint; //I tried with NSInteger as well and got the same error code

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeInt:self.index forKey:@"self.index"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self.index = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"self.index"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

Comment: So actually you need to remove the [super] from the suggested code above for both the encode and decode. If you leave the [super... command in, the integer does not decode to the correct value. I don't know why (didn't find a reason in the doc, but as a head's up to other newbies.